# Angular: Multiline strings and routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 5 and TypeScript 2.7.1, why is the routerLink directive not clickable on the following multiline string ?

`
`<div class="geopoint-infowindow">
   <a [routerLink]="/users/${user.id}">${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</a>
</div>`

`

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<a [routerLink]="/users/${user.id}">{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</a>
```

to this

```
<a [routerLink]="`/users/${user.id}`">{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</a>
```

The string interpolation doesn't work without the **``**

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. The link is outputted as plain HTML not as a directive. If I use a simple href, now I lose the routing mechanism and the app is reloading which is normal.

Comment: Please update your question with a proper description of what you are trying to do and how you do it. Given the components and the templates code as example of your current implementation.